# Does yii2 uses the magickwand extension?

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, php-extension, magickwand

I'm getting this random error in my Yii2 project

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/magickwand.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/magickwand.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory' in Unknown:0
```

I want to know if yii2 uses this php extension somewhere so I can install it or remove it from my php installation to prevent the error to keep showing up.

Thanks

Comment: you can check the dependency in yii2 requirement. You can run [requirements.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/requirements/requirements.php) to confirm.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of that file, I checked and looks like is being used by the imageMagick extension. thanks